# Adding an element in between of an array without affecting index traverse

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, loops, optimization

I need a effective solution (space + time) for the below problem,

**Current Code**

```
#define MAX_CHAR 26

char alphabet[MAX_CHAR] = 
{
   'A',
   'B',
   'C',
   'D',
   'E',
   ...
   ...
   'Z'
}

print_first_alphabet_number (Str)
{
   for (i=0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)
   {
     if (Str[0] == start_letter[i])
     {
        printf ("%d", i);
        return;
     }
   }
    return;
}
```

**Sample IO**

```
Apple -> 0
Door  -> 3
Zoo   -> 25
```

**Modified Code**

```
#define MAX_CHAR 27

char alphabet[MAX_CHAR] = 
{
   'A',
   'B',
   '@',
   'C',
   'D',
   'E',
   ...
   ...
   'Z'
}
```

**Expectation**

`print_first_alphabet_number` should be modified to get the same result of sample IO.

Thanks in advance..

**Edit**

This is not the exact problem, this is just an example..

Comment: Does that "@" char in between the alphabet have any significance? Why not just put it at the end?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAX_CHAR 27

char alphabet[MAX_CHAR] = 
{
   'A',
   'B',
   '@',
   'C',
   'D',
   'E',
   ...
   ...
   'Z'
}

print_first_alphabet_number (Str)
{
   for (i=0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)
   {
     if (Str[0] == start_letter[i])
     {
        printf ("%d", start_letter[i] - 'A');
        return;
     }
   }
    return;
}
```

## Edit

Or as @nico-schertler suggested, if you just need to print the integer same as the alphabetical order or capital letters, you can achieve this without any character array and loop.

```
printf ("%d", Str[0] - 'A');
```

Comment: You don't need a loop for that. Just `printf ("%d", Str[0] - 'A');`

Comment: I've just  tried to keep the code same as before as possible

Answer (score 0):

It's hard do understand what are you doing, you only want the index of alpha values?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 27

char alphabet[] = 
{
   'A',
   'B',
   '@',
   'C',
   'D',
   'E',
   ...
   'Z'
};

void print_first_alphabet_number(char * Str)
{
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++)
    {
        if (Str[0] == alphabet[i])
        {
            printf("%d\n", ret);
            return;
        }
        if(isalpha(alphabet[i])) ret++;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    print_first_alphabet_number("Door");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you cannot distinguish inserted element by value, just by index, so this is the input. On more insertion, an array of inserted offsets should be organized.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int idx;
    char abc[] = "AB@CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int skip = 2; /* index to be skipped */
    int num_skip = 0;
    int size = sizeof(abc)/sizeof(abc[0]);
    char ch;
    printf( "char [A-Z]: " );
    (void)scanf( "%c", &ch );
    for( idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx )
    {
        if( skip == idx ) { ++num_skip; }
        if( ch == abc[idx] )
        {
            printf( "%d\n", idx - num_skip );
            idx = size;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```